# Как обновить python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-3.8, parrot-os

B `parrot os` стоит Python `3.7`, нужно обновить до python `3.8` и установить pip. `sudo apt-get update` не  работает.

Comment: На любой Linux системе лучше не трогать (не пытаться обновить) системный Python. Установите python 3.8 отдельно - `sudo apt-get install python3.8`, потом запускать в терминале как `python3.8`. Команда `sudo apt-get update` сама по себе обновляет не установленные пакеты, а только информацию о пакетах.

Comment: А как установить на него pip

Comment: Он уже установлен, запускать как `python3.8 -m pip`